# MongoDB command createUser requires authentication

Tags: database, mongodb

I just installed Mongo DB on my Linux Server. Now I want to create an main admin user.
I followed the offical docs, but every time I run the command I get:

```
uncaught exception: Error: couldn't add user: command createUser requires authentication: _getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13 DB.prototype.createUser@src/mongo/shell/db.js:1386:11 @(shell):1:1
```

I really don't know what I should do to fix this error.
Inside the **/etc/mongod.conf** config file authentication is disabled:

```
security:
    authorization: "disabled"
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: Is there a keyfile configured?

Comment: Are you sure the mongod process is using config file `/etc/mongod.conf`? Did you restart the mongod process after changing the config file?.

Comment: It should really not matter, but try to remove the quotes.

Comment: What do you get from [db.serverCmdLineOpts()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.serverCmdLineOpts/)?

Answer (score -1):

To create the first user, you need to have authentication enabled and use the localhost passthrough: open mongoshell (the `mongo` command) from the same server in which the database is running.

Note that the passthrough is valid only when you connect via localhost and when no users have yet been created (once you create the first user, you will need to authenticate to perform any tasks). If you already created a user but don't remember the password, you will need to delete the entire `dbPath` folder, restart mongod and then use the passthrough to create the first user.

Comment: According config file, authorization is disabled. The localhost exception works also when you connect from remote machine (provided `bindIp` permits them). And when you have forgotten your admin password, then you can simply restart the MongoDB without authorization, connect without credentials and reset the password. There is no reason to purge the entire `dbPath`!